# Checking duplicates in terminal?

Tags: scripting, shell

The following code prints me a long list of files with hashes and file names

```
md5sum *.java
```

I have tried unsuccessfully to list the lines where identical hashes occur, so that I can then remove identical files.

How can you filter and delete identical files which have same content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `fdupes` and less view on duplicates

Use `fdupes` which is a commandline program such as

```
fdupes -r /home/masi/Documents/ > /tmp/1 
less -M +Gg /tmp/1
```

which finds all duplicates and stores them in file in temp. 
The less command shows you the line position of all lines and your proceeding as percentage. 
I found `fdupes` from this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/3866/25388) and its clear Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fdupes). 
You can install it by homebrew in OSX and by `apt-get` in Linux.

### Use `fdupes` interactively with possible deletes

Run

```
fdupes -rd /home/masi/Documents
```

which let's you choose which copy to delete or not, example view of the interactive work:

```
Set 4 of 2664, preserve files [1 - 2, all]: all

   [+] /home/masi/Documents/Exercise 10 - 1.4.2015/task.bib
   [+] /home/masi/Documents/Exercise 9 - 16.3.2015/task.bib

[1] /home/masi/Documents/Celiac_disease/jcom_jun02_celiac.pdf
[2] /home/masi/Documents/turnerWhite/jcom_jun02_celiac.pdf

Set 5 of 2664, preserve files [1 - 2, all]: 2

   [-] /home/masi/Documents/Celiac_disease/jcom_jun02_celiac.pdf
   [+] /home/masi/Documents/turnerWhite/jcom_jun02_celiac.pdf
```

where you see that I have 2664 duplicates. 
It would be nice to have some static file which would save the settings about my wanted duplicates; I opened a thread about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31630714/54964). 
For instance, I have same bib -files in some exercises and homework so do not ask second time when the user wants the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
md5sum *.java | sort | uniq -d -w32
```

This tells uniq to only compare the first 32 character, which is only the md5 sum, not the filenames.

EDIT: If -w isn't available, try:

```
md5sum *.java | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -d
```

The downside is that you won't know which files have these duplicate checksums... anyway, if there aren't too much checksums, you can use

```
md5sum *.java | grep 0bee89b07a248e27c83fc3d5951213c1
```

to get the filenames afterwards (the checksum above is just an example). I'm sure there's a way to do all this in a shell script, too.

Comment: Thank you! I observed that Mac does not have the option -w. I think that the reason is that they do not want many commands have same features. How can you parse the name out without -w option?

Comment: By the way, before anyone tries to bruteforce the md5sum above, it's for a file that contains "abc" ;)

Answer (score 2):

Even beter:

```
md5sum *.java | sort | uniq -d
```

That only prints the duplicate lines.

Comment: The code gives me nothing as an output. The reason may be that although two files have the same hash, they still have different names. We should first somehow filter the names out.

Answer (score 1):

This lists all the files, putting a blank line between duplicates:

```
$ md5sum *.txt \ 
  | sort       \
  | perl -pe '($y)=split; print "\n" unless $y eq $x; $x=$y'

05aa3dad11b2d97568bc506a7080d4a3  b.txt
2a517c8a78f1e1582b4ce25e6a8e4953  n.txt
e1254aebddc54f1cbc9ed2eacce91f28  a.txt
e1254aebddc54f1cbc9ed2eacce91f28  k.txt
e1254aebddc54f1cbc9ed2eacce91f28  p.txt
$
```

To only print 1st of each group:

```
$ md5sum *.txt | sort | perl -ne '($y,$f)=split; print "$f\n" unless $y eq $x; $x=$y'
b.txt
n.txt
a.txt
$
```

if you're brave, change the "unless" to "if" and then

```
$ rm `md5sum ...`
```

to delete all but the first of each group

Comment: there should be backticks around the "md5sum ..." in the "rm" command line, but I can't edit again