# Grep in shell scripting

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to write a shell script to eliminate duplicate files, but I got stuck early...

```
find $1 -type f -exec md5sum {} + > /tmp/$$
find $1 -type f -exec md5sum {} + | sort  | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -d > \
    /tmp/$$.spec
```

At this point, /tmp/PID holds MD5 (space) filename , and /tmp/PID.spec holds the hashes that are repeated. How do I search for every repeated hash in /tmp/PID?

```
cat /tmp/$$ | grep /tmp/$$.spec
```

returns no result, but I thought this would go line by line through my complete file, and only return lines that matched with the hash from the .spec file. Apparently not.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove identical files in UNIX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400574/remove-identical-files-in-unix/2400784) and [Checking duplicates in terminal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621708/checking-duplicates-in-terminal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -f /tmp/$$.spec /tmp/$$`

use the -f option will do the work